# GUI Programming in C using GTK+ on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Sever (RHEL) 5.11

Tags: c, linux, unix, gtk, redhat

I am trying to run a simple GUI program written in C, which uses GTK+ 2.0 in Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server (RHEL) 5.11. At the moment I am using Anizo Lite a Windows Terminal emulator to get onto RHEL 5.11.

Mentioned below is the C program code which is from the simple example in the following link:

http://zetcode.com/gui/gtk2/firstprograms/

simple.c

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

GtkWidget *window;
gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
gtk_widget_show(window);

g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);

gtk_main();

return 0;

}
```

The video links below gives you an idea of what I am trying to achieve.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C0gZE3ZsElM

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zpkpn-AJLAA

When I run pkg-config --cflags gtk+-2.0 I get the following information:

```
-I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 
-I/usr/lib64/gtk-2.0/include 
-I/usr/include/atk-1.0 
-I/usr/include/cairo 
-I/usr/include/pango-1.0 
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 
-I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include 
-I/usr/include/freetype2 
-I/usr/include/libpng12
```

Then when I run pkg-config --libs gtk+-2.0 I get the following information:

-L/lib64 
   -lgtk-x11-2.0 
   -lgdk-x11-2.0 
   -latk-1.0 
   -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 
   -lm 
   -lpangocairo-1.0 
   -lpango-1.0 
   -lcairo 
   -lgobject-2.0 
   -lgmodule-2.0 
   -ldl 
   -lglib-2.0

Afterwards I compiled the GKT application on Unix using **cc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0` simple.c -o simple** and run **./simple** I get the following error message:

(simple:25384): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:

When I checked the **DISPLAY** environment variable using echo $DISPLAY it is currently set at **0.0**. Having looked at various forums for solutions I understand the value of the environment is along the lines of hostname:D:S which 'D' is the number of displays and 'S' is the number of screens.

I have tried to export DISPLAY=host_ip:0 but that did not work even tried from switching my username to root and that produced the same error.

I checked to see if X Server is running using 'ps -e |grep X' gives me **4406 tty7     01:37:02 Xorg**, which means X Server is already running.

Then I checked in the server's sshd_config **(/etc/ssh/sshd_config)** to make sure the X11Forwarding option is enabled but not sure if FowardX11 has anything to do with it at the moment that is set to 'no' and is commented out.

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

Any suggestions or guidance on how to get the issue resolved would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to run an X server on your Windows machine. Also, 0:0 is probably a wrong display if you're connecting with ssh, you need to see something like 10:0.

Comment: Strange, I just compilet with **gcc program.c -o program `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0`** and works fine for me. Ubuntu 15.04 64BIT. Any way on linux try to add **Defaults env_keep=DISPLAY**  in  **/etc/sudoers** and see if there are some changes.

Comment: Are you sure Anzio Lite supports UI applications? Are you able of running any other UI application under Anzio session? If you open a VNC session to your Linux desktop, are you able of running your application as expected ?

Comment: @n.m. - Thanks will need to explore X server in more detail.

Comment: @Michi - I have tried your suggestion but doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @LiMar - Good question. I have contacted Anzio and they say it does not UI applications. I am able to open a VNC session into Linux and can run UI applications from the desktop but this is not a possible solution for the project I am working on. However, it might solve the program issue. But I think moving forward I will have to find a different emulator that supports UI applications.